# VBA - Copy Worksheets to Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to create a macro to copy the entire worksheets from a closed workbook to the current one I have open..

The code is working fine but VLOOKUP from the closed workbook have changed it value when the worksheet been copied over to the active workbook.

```
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

fileStr = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Template\EQ\Closed Workbook.xlsm"

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

wbk2.Sheets("A").Copy Before:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
wbk2.Sheets("B").Copy Before:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
wbk2.Sheets("C").Copy Before:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
wbk2.Sheets("D").Copy Before:=wbk1.Sheets(1)

wbk2.Close
```

The function automatically changed to:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B14;'[Closed Workbook1]EQ LIST'!A:B;2;FALSE);" ")
```

Instead of:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B14;'EQ LIST'!A:B;2;FALSE);" ")
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Simply replace some of the workbook name with nothing.

The code I am using:

```
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set rng = Sheets("PICK SHEET").Range("B3:B10")

For Each cel In rng cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "[Close Workbook1]", "")

Next
```